# Scan from Xerox WorkCentre 3025

Tags: 16.04, scanner, xerox

I have a multifunctional printer Xerox WorkCentre. I can print and scan from my computer. However, I cannot make scans from the device, when choosing scanning to PC. Is there a way to scan directly from the scanner instead of computer? I use Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: In Linux you will need to use a program like `Simple Scan` already installed to scan from the PC. I don't know about this specific printer/scanner, but usually there is no way to scan from the device to a Linux PC.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the document scanned you may want to follow this :

- Install vsftpd

  ```
  sudo apt-get install vsftpd
  ```
- As root, create the directory `/home/ftpscan` (read only for everybody except root) and  `/home/ftpscan/write` (read-write for everybody).

  ```
  # sudo mkdir /home/ftpscan
  # sudo mkdir /home/ftpscan/write
  # sudo chmod ugo+rwx /home/ftpscan/write
  ```
- modify the configuration of vsftpd to include those lines :

  ```
  # edit /etc/vsftpd.conf with your favorite text editor
  # enable anonymous user : any password accepted
  anonymous_enable=YES
  # Do not need those local users
  local_enable=NO
  #allow anonymous to write
  write_enable=YES
  anon_mkdir_write_enable=YES
  anon_upload_enable=YES
  anon_root=/home/ftpscan
  # Allows everybody to read the item placed anonymously
  chown_upload_mode=0666
  anon_umask=000
  ```
- `restart service vsftpd`
- Open the port 21 (FTP) for your printer (I think you may want to use `UFW`).
- Configure your printer via the http interface : I do not know the english words, may be you can help.  We take a webbrowser and follow

  ```
   HTTP://<IP> 
   -> "Carnet d'adressse"              / ? 3th item
   -> "Carnet d'addresse PC/Server"    / ? 
   -> "Carnet d'adresses PC / Serveur" / ? 
   -> "ajouter"                        / add 
    Change those fields (<.> means that it must be interpreted)
    - Name is free
    - Type of network   == FTP server and not SMB server
    - Host Address      == <your computer hostanme or your computer ip>
    - Port number       == <empty or 21> 
    - connection name   == anonymous
    - password          == <anything or nothing>
    - path to directory == write
  ```

That is very creative names. Xerox is not giving neither easy nor standard interface.  I was expecting something more admirable from this company.

Answer (score -3):

**Solution for Windows:**

Scan to Network PC

1. Open the Xerox Easy Printer Manager application. Select

   > Start -> Programs or All Programs -> Xerox Printers -> Xerox Easy Printer Manager -> Easy Printer Manager.
2. Select the Switch to Advanced Mode button at the top of the window.
3. Select your machine in the Printer List and add it, if required.
4. Select the Scan to PC Settings button. The Scan to PC Settings screen appears.
5. Select Enable Scan from Device Panel.
6. Select your required settings for Scan Settings:

   • Output Color
   • Resolution
   • Original Size
7. Select your required settings for File Settings:

   • Save To
   • File Format
   • OCR Language
   • Delete Original Image after OCR

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This looks like a Windows solution rather than Ubuntu solution. Is this software available for Ubuntu? If so, please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1078144/edit) your question and add how to install the program.